# How to keep the last word of a string column (pyspark)

Tags: pyspark

I have a string column in my dataset
I want to keep only the last word using pyspark

Exemple :

MyColumn

abc jdj a500

jsh hsj z500

ajd jdi d500

I want to get this:

MyColumn

a500

z500

d500

I think I have to use split function but I don't succeed to do this
The delimiter of the words is the space: " "

I tried this :

```
Mydata = Mydata.withColumn('KeepLast', F.trim((F.split(F.col('MyColumn')," ")[-1])))
```

But the KeepLast column is null for all values
Thanks in advance for helping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `element_at` to extract the last element after the `split`.

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('abc jdj a500', )]).toDF(['strcol']). \
    withColumn('new', func.element_at(func.split('strcol', ' '), -1)). \
    show()

# +------------+----+
# |      strcol| new|
# +------------+----+
# |abc jdj a500|a500|
# +------------+----+
```